# Elementwise comparison of two vectors while ignoring all NaN's in between

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, nan

I have two vectors 1x5000. They consist of numbers like this:

`vec1 = [NaN NaN 2 NaN NaN NaN 5 NaN 8 NaN NaN 7 NaN 5 NaN 3 NaN 4]`

`vec2 = [NaN 2 NaN NaN 5 NaN NaN NaN 8 NaN 1 NaN NaN NaN 5 NaN NaN NaN]`

I would like to check if the order of the numbers are equal, independent of the `NaN`s. But I do not want to remove the `NaN`s (Not-a-Number) since I will use them later. So now I create a new vector and call it `results`. Once they come in the same order, it is correct and we fill `results` with `1`. If the next numbers are not equal we add `0` to `results`.

An example `results` would look like this for `vec1` and `vec2`:
`[1 1 1 0 1 0 0]`

The first 3 numbers are the same, then 7 is compared to 1 which gives 0, then 5 compared to 5 is true which gives 1. Then the last two numbers are missing which gives 0.

One reason that I don't want to remove the `NaN`s is that I have a time vector 1x500 and somehow I want to get the time for each 1 and 0 (in a new vector). Is that possible too?

Help is super appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
temp1 = vec1(~isnan(vec1));
temp2 = vec2(~isnan(vec2));
m = min(numel(temp1), numel(temp2));
M = max(numel(temp1), numel(temp2));
results = [(temp1(1:m) == temp2(1:m)), false(1,M-m)];
```

Note that here `results` is a binary array. If you need it numeric, you can convert it to double for instance.

Regarding your concern about `NaN`s, depends on what you want to do with your arrays. If you are going to process them, it is more convenient to remove the `NaN`s. In order to keep the track of things you can keep the index of the kept elements:

```
id1 = find(~isnan(vec1));
vec1 = vec1(id1);

vec1 =

     2     5     8     7     5     3     4

id1 =

     3     7     9    12    14    16    18

% and same for vec2
```

If you decide to remove the `NaN`s, the solution will be the same, with all `temp`s replaced with `vec`.

Comment: This seems to work perfectly, thanks! Just one question, I have a vector time1 and time2. For each 1 and 0, could I get out the time of vec1 and vec2? The time vector is of the same length.

Comment: I am assuming that `time1` is a vector of times with each element corresponding to one element in `vec1`. Then yes, you can have all the times of the `NaN`-free `vec1` in this way: `newtime1 = time1(id1);`

Comment: Correct regarding the time vector, I automatically want to get the time for each 1 and 0 of the vec1 and vec2. Can this be made?

Comment: There is a problem here; You are checking the values to be equal, regardless of their index in `vec`s or their time, but just according to their order. How are you certain that `2` and `2` in your example belong to the same time instance?

Comment: They do not belong to the same time instance, I just want to get out time. Because I will later on compare how many second passed between the numbers in vec1 and vec2.

Comment: Then `Tones1 = time1(id1(results))` and `Tzeros1 = time1(id1(~results))` should be what you are looking for ;)

Answer (score 1):

This would be my solution, using a mix of logical indexing and the find function. Returning the timestamps for the 1's and 0's is actually more tedious than finding the 1's and 0's.

```
vec1 = [NaN NaN 2 NaN NaN NaN 5 NaN 8 NaN NaN 7 NaN 5 NaN 3 NaN 4];
vec2 = [NaN 2 NaN NaN 5 NaN NaN NaN 8 NaN 1 NaN NaN NaN 5 NaN NaN NaN];
t=1:numel(vec1);

ind1=find(~isnan(vec1));
ind2=find(~isnan(vec2));
v1=vec1(ind1);
v2=vec2(ind2);
if length(v1)>length(v2)
   ibig=1; 
else
    ibig=2;
end
n=min(length(v1),length(v2));
N=max(length(v1),length(v2));
v=false(1,N);
v(1:n)=v1(1:n)==v2(1:n);

t_ones1=t(ind1(v));
t_ones2=t(ind2(v));
if ibig==1
    t_zeros1=t(ind1(~v));
    t_zeros2=t(ind2(~v(1:n)));
else
    t_zeros1=t(ind1(~v(1:n)));
    t_zeros2=t(ind2(~v));
end
```